# Схлопывание margin у родителя и потомка

Tags: html, css

Прочитал то что для "отключения" схлопывания у родителя и потомка можно задать свойство `display: inline-block;` для одного элемента участвующего в схлопывании. Вопрос: какие есть минусы у данного способа?

Comment: попробуйте и сами определите + и -, а вообще в сети достаточно много информации о схлопывании

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ширина по умолчанию не 100% и блоки будут в одну строку. но это легко лечится.